# Comparing a Table column to the connected user in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

im in needed of help, im doing some exercises with a a oracle database and do not know how to do this:

I have a table called users that have information of the users that connect to the DB, what i want is a procedure where to show the information of a specific row where the connected user is compared to the user in the table.

i do not how to compared a data in a table to the connected user, more like i dont know how "work" or what limitations have the "user" parameter to be implemented this way

Sorry if my petition its a little confusing english is not my main language.

EX: i have a user in the table users, that have a serial id, username,password,name, surname1 and surname2 and i want the procedure to show me the information of this user in particular, but i do want that if for example im connected with "pedro" user to the db this procedure show me the info about the user pedro and if i change the user connected to another like Paul the information of the select change to Paul.

Comment: Are these users 'database' users (as in CREATE USER FRED IDENTIFIED BY .) or are the _application_ users, wherein the application uses its own database account to connect on behalf of the app user. It would be very unusual to maintain your own table of _database_ users.    In the end, you need to read and heed https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You say you are keeping 'password'.  I do hope you are not keeping it as either clear text or a simple encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option might be to use the `USER` function.

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@orcl
Connected.

SQL> select user from dual;

USER
------------------------------
SCOTT

SQL>
```

Therefore you'd

```
select serial id, 
       username,
       password,
       name, 
       surname1,
       surname2 
from users
where username = user;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the currently connected user with

```
select sys_context('USERENV','CURRENT_USER') from dual;
```